# Splitting a grammar rule in Bison

Tags: c, grammar, bison

I have a Bison rule

```
block: LBRACE  { some code } decls stmts RBRACE {more code } 
     ;
```

The issue is in the "more code" section, I have

```
$$ = $3 ;
```

Basically, I want the return value of block to be stmts. When I do this, Bison says "$3 of block has no type." If I remove the code block containing some code and stick it into the latter block, bison does not complain. I have stmts and all of its derivatives declared as types. So is this not allowed by Bison? I can make changes to the grammar to accommodate this, but it will be tedious and much easier to just use the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$4` to refer to `stmts`.  Since you have a [mid-rule action](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Actions.html#Mid_002dRule-Actions), all proceeding symbol numbers are offset as the action itself can have a value.

The corresponding component numbers are:
**$1** `LBRACE`
**$2** `{ some code }`
**$3** `decls`
**$4** `stmts`
**$5** `RBRACE`
**$6** `{ more code }`